# What SQL injection syntax should I send in payload of rest API to test it properly

Tags: api, security, sql-injection

We are creating a API automation suite and we need to write/test sql injection testcase.

I have use SQLMAP for same to test my api for sql-injection.
 Now I need to send some parameter in my test script to test these testcases.

I have tried syntax like:-

- or 1=1
- '1' ='1'
- ' OR ''='

What other I can try.
Do it work with JSON Payload POST request as well or should I tried this for GET request only.

please suggest a good approach so that I can accomplish my task correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by using one of the several collections of SQL Injection and XSS payload strings hosted on GitHub. For example: [SQL/XSS Injection Strings](https://github.com/danTaler/detectionString).
If you want a serious testing for vulnerabilities you should use a prooven penetration testing framework like [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) or a [SQL Injection tool](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sql%20injection&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults).

Comment: Thanks Ёжик в тумане for quick reply..  Can I send these sql syntax in POST request ?. Is it a right way to do it? ..

Comment: yes, it is, the attackers will try it in all existing ways